# Accessing web-service properties

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, reference

I am building an application using web-services to send and receive messages from our core accounting system to a provider.

I have added a web-service to my project, and I am trying to build a Soap Body to go in the message to the web-service.

All my other web-services are working fine, and I am only having trouble with accessing the properties that I need to populate on this one.

None of the properties in the object browser view are available in my variable **wsSoapBody**

Here is the web-service in the Object Browser of VS 2013:
[image]

I have declared the web-service in my class like this:

```
using EvryCardManagement.ws.card.DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdate_V3_0;
```

My class is declared like this:

```
namespace EvryCardManagement
{
    class DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType
    {
```

So in my function to create the soap body I have the below code:

```
private DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody(string message)
{
    /* Split message into an array */
    string[] aMessage = message.Replace("_", "").Split('\t');
    //CardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = new CardHolderRuleUpdateType();

    DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = new DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType (); 

    /* Required and Mandatory fields */
    wsSoapBody.InstId = aMessage[(int) CardHolderRuleUpdateType.InstId].ToString();
    wsSoapBody.CardNo = aMessage[(int)CardHolderRuleUpdateType.CardNo].ToString();
    wsSoapBody.VersionNo = aMessage[(int)CardHolderRuleUpdateType.VersionNo].ToString();

    wsSoapBody.SMSNo = aMessage[(int)CardHolderRuleUpdateType.SMSNo].ToString();
    if (aMessage[(int)CardHolderRuleUpdateType.RemoveSMSRule].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        wsSoapBody.SMSNo = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int iRule = 13; iRule <= 29; iRule+=2)
        {
            int isRule = 0;
            if (aMessage[iRule] != "") isRule = Convert.ToInt16(aMessage[iRule]);
            if (isRule == 1)
            {
                switch (iRule)
                {
                    case 13:
                        wsSoapBody.region1 = "1";
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        wsSoapBody.region2 = "2";

                    ... cut for brevity
```

So I am supposed to be able to reference all the properties in `CardHolderRuleUpdateType` by the below variable declaration:

```
CardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = new CardHolderRuleUpdateType();
```

I have also tried:

```
DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType.CardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = 
             new DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType.CardHolderRuleUpdateType();
```

Now, when I use `CardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = new CardHolderRuleUpdateType();` I have found that I can do this:

[image]

so the properties are definitely there, and I can access them, but I don't know how.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The top screenshtp shows the properties of a `DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType` but in your code you are using  `CardHolderRuleUpdateType`. These would seem to be different types.

Comment: @BenRobinson: yes this is correct, and when I use that as in `DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType wsSoapBody = new DCSSCardHolderRuleUpdateType ();` I can access the properties like `wsSoapBody.InstId` but still have no access to the properties like *Region1* etc

Comment: Can you update your post to demonstrate that, because at the moment what you have posted is obviously wrong as you are comparing 2 completely different types.